# laravel webpack mix error where `{{}}` in text

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I'm use Laravel 5.8

I have some text data for example my stored text in db is:

```
 <div class="card-header">
    <h1>
      <span class="fa fa-user-plus"></span> {{ __('Register') }}
    </h1>
  </div>
```

and my blade code is:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Author Code
    </td>
    <td>
        {{$athor->code}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

The webpack mix think this part of my code but this a usual string only.

The page goes to white, I can replace `{{`,`}}` with `str_replace` for this error, but what is the best solution?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what is the problem, what is Webpack's job in ur setup?

Comment: @felixmosh my problem is where in the my text has `{{` webpack mix think it's part of my code, this is default laravel default config.

Comment: How webpack gets those templates in the first place?

Comment: Check my yesterday's answer maybe there is similar root of problem. If so you should store DB value as `{!! '{{ __("Register") }}' !!}`, not as `{{ __('Register') }}`.

Comment: @Tpojka hey man this text inserted by user I can't determine what they insert.

Comment: Not sure. Saving HTML in db is tough part. You are allowing users to save `{{` and `}}` strings? Not good way imho.